# Last route is always called

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I have two routes as following (in router.js).

```
this.resource('records', function() {
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:id'});
    this.route('delete', {path: '/:user_name'});
});
```

when I refreshed the page when i was in edit route. But the page is loaded with the delete route.

If i have the routes as following,

```
this.resource('records', function() {
    this.route('delete', {path: '/:user_name'});
    this.route('edit', {path: '/:id'});
});
```

Now if i refresh the page, when i am in delete route, the page would load with edit route.

When i press the browser back button also same problem occurs. The last route in a resource is called. But I want it to be loaded with the same route that I was in earlier.

Anyone had encountered this problem? If so please help me in this.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Route is getting overridden by  `this.route('edit', {path: '/:id'});` you need to put some other string before or after your edit route

```
this.resource('records', function() {
    this.route('delete', {path: '/:user_name'});
    this.route('edit', {path: '/edit/:id'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks @Vicky.. I was thinking how to use the same parameter for more than one route.. It helped me.. meanwhile we can use like this..!! :-) 

'this.resource('records', function() {
    this.route('delete', {path: '/delete/:id'});
    this.route('edit', {path: '/edit/:id'});
});'